# JavaScript: can I get the full url including the domain, the filename and the protocol?

Tags: javascript

I am sure this should be possible but when I look at google, all it tells me is how to get the filename and stuff, I don't want this.

I am looking for this because I use Weebly as my webhost and it only allows for .html files - when you click "Home" you are brought to /index.html and when you open the site there isn't  a /index.html.

What would be a plus is if I can add (using an if statement of course) JS that redirects if the site's url == http://kingdomofmuqtasid.weebly.com/index.html and points the body to: http://kingdomofmuqtasid.weebly.com.

PS: can the code be placed *inside* the body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.location.href
```

is the full URL of the current page.  See the [MDN doc page for `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) for more info.

You could put this code in the `<head>` section or `<body>` section of your page to do the redirection.

```
<script>
if (window.location.href == "http://kingdomofmuqtasid.weebly.com/index.html") {
    window.location = "http://kingdomofmuqtasid.weebly.com/";
}
</script>
```

P.S. This code goes in whatever page is served up when the viewer goes to "http://kingdomofmuqtasid.weebly.com/index.html".

Comment: Thanks, but... how would I place that into an if statement so I can redirect between the 2 urls I listed?

Comment: Sorry, I didnt see that! I just was notified on the other answer browsing the site so I jumped to the bottom. THANKS. I'll try it and mark it as an answer.

Comment: Ok, I cannot accept the answer until 3 minutes are up but, thank you very much, the code works brilliant!

Comment: Semi off-topic, but ideally you shouldn't be doing redirects on the client-side, you should be doing them server-side.

Comment: @market agreed. similar to going to the store, buying ice cream for your significant other, going back home, finding out its the wrong ice cream, etc etc

Comment: @market, that is correct as I understand but I use Weebly, they don't allow for editing PHP or anything like that, the thing is, I blog mostly so I am not really bothered to rent a server :D. Thanks any way. PS, is it bad for SEO? because the pages were duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.location to get these data.
With the code above you can iterate over the window.location and get the data that you are needing.

```
var location = window.location;

for ( var i in location ) {
    console.log( i + " " + location[i] );
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks but... I need to somehow make an if statement that allows for redirects, I mean, how would I do that, I am a total newb to js, I have never used it.

Comment: @rgbc, jfriend00 already said this in his answer. Take a look.

Comment: I just checked now, sorry, when I opened the page, I skimmed to the bottom. Thanks for your help.